# How to develop a delivery carrier in Odoo 14?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I searched a lot about delivery providers in Odoo. I found some simple comments in the project source and some sampling modules in the app store. Does anyone know how to implement a new carrier?

This is the comment in odoo delivery addon:

```
''' A Shipping Provider

In order to add your own external provider, follow these steps:

1. Create your model MyProvider that _inherit 'delivery.carrier'
2. Extend the selection of the field "delivery_type" with a pair
   ('<my_provider>', 'My Provider')
3. Add your methods:
   <my_provider>_rate_shipment
   <my_provider>_send_shipping
   <my_provider>_get_tracking_link
   <my_provider>_cancel_shipment
   _<my_provider>_get_default_custom_package_code
   (they are documented hereunder)
'''
```

I follow the steps but nothing happend.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing new carrier in Odoo is considered a complicated task. However you may need to see the existing sample modules from enterprise addons like the following: `delivery_bpost`, `delivery_dhl`, `delivery_easypost`, `delivery_fedex`, `delivery_ups`, `delivery_usps`.

Comment: Thanks, I download free deliveries and try to figure out how they work. I may answer my own question soon.